# List of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

Very simple question that I can’t find an answer for.

Let’s say i have a list of multiple lists inside this list.

```
List_1 = [[“name”,”Richard”,”age”,36],[“name”,”Andrea”,”age”,44],[”name”,”Steve”,”age”,56]]
```

What i would need is to convert each list inside “main” list to dictionary so as a result there would be 1 list where inside is multiple dictionaries.

Thanks for helping me out this is just making me crazy..

Comment: Why are you doing this? This seems like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. You could try to look into dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: "convert each list inside “main” list to dictionary so as a result there would be 1 list where inside is multiple dictionaries." "Convert" **how**? What should the result be, for this input, and why? Also: please make sure that you do not actually use `“”` symbols in your code; they are **not valid** for surrounding a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible one liner if you'd prefer:

```
new_list = [{row[i]: row[i+1] for i in range(0, len(row), 2)} for row in List_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a basic for loop.

```py
new_list = []
for sublist in list_1:
    Put your code to convert the sublist to a dict here
    new_list.append(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for i in range(len(List_1)):
    List_1[i] = {'name': List_1[i][1], 'age': List_1[i][3]}
```

Where `List_1` is a list of the type defined in the question.